# Python - convert to a lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

How can I convert the following to a lambda function in Python (v 2.7) ?

```
def my_func(obj): 
   if obj.type: 
       return obj.name
   else: 
       return obj.type
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use a [*ternary operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) / *[conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)*:

```
lambda obj: obj.name if obj.type else obj.type
```

Though, it seems you need to flip the things you return - return `type` only if is truthy:

```
lambda obj: obj.type if obj.type else obj.name
```